# Is Array.Contains thread safe on a readonly array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, thread-safety

Is Array.Contains thread safe in the following context.

A static array is declared and initialized with 4 elements in a function.

```
Static validRotations() As Integer = {0, 90, 180, 270}
```

It is then only accessed using validRotations.Contains(rotation) in the same function.

The function is called at any time from many different threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, immutable structures are thread safe.

If the data never changes, you can access it safely from multiple threads.

Issues with multi-threading only occur when you change data (update/add).

Answer (score 1):

This will be safe, provided you aren't modifying the array (which, in your case, you're not).

This is compiled to a local static field within the class, and initialized prior to use by any of the methods.  As it's not being changed, and only read, it's basically just doing array reads in parallel, which is safe.